# Unable to update the docker image. Error : repository does not exist or may require 'docker login''

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, docker-watchtower

I have deploy [watchtower](https://github.com/v2tec/watchtower) which automatically update running Docker containers inside **Docker Swarm**.

I run this Docker Swarm on two **AWS EC2** servers and use AWS ECR as Docker registry.

to avoid `aws ecr get-login` I have used **Amazon ECR Docker Credential Helper** which Automatically gets credentials for Amazon ECR on docker push/docker pull and no need to login ech 12 hours.

Problem is watchtower is throwing a error like :

> time="2019-03-12T03:41:10Z" level=info msg="Unable to update container /crmproxy.1.wop3c1u2qktbkab8rukrlrgr6, err='Error response from daemon: pull access denied for 00000000000.dkr..amazonaws.com/crm, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login''. Proceeding to next."

I am sure that is not about login to ECR. I have correctly linked credentials into WATCHTOWER contaiener using ***docker-compose.yml*** file.

here is the watchtower configurations on docker-compose.yml file.

```
  watchtower:
    image: v2tec/watchtower
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        - ~/.docker/config.json:/config.json
    command: --interval 30
```

In my research about this issue,  I saw others has same problem as me and there is person has fixed it him self but i don't understand it.

this is the what i found : [solution that is unclear](https://github.com/v2tec/watchtower/issues/38)

I don't exactly know this answer is correct or not. but he has said :

> The problem was that I installed docker as root. Now installed with
>   the ec2-user of the Amazon Linux AMI and working

Please help me to avoid this problem that I'm facing. I tried so many times.
Any help would be adavantage to me.

Answer (score 0):

There's an additional dot in your image url. Might that be the reason for your issue?

```
  00000000000.dkr..amazonaws.com/crm
                  ^
```

Also, you may just add the ec2-user to the docker group to let it execute docker commands as well: `sudo usermod -aG docker ec2-user`. No need to reinstall.